# Untrustworthy Projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When opening a project you may have recently downloaded, Visual Studio 2013 briefly warns you to only open projects from trustworthy sources. What are some of the risks to opening projects? Can a project do any harm to your system before compilation, and what damage is possible? Are there any indicators you should be aware of before actually opening projects from "untrustworthy" sources? (Not that I can think of any)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Attack Surface within Visual Studio

There are many attack vectors within Visual Studio. All of them are by design. We developers want complete control over our systems within the build process. Unfortunately, when we say *"I want to delete the contents of the cache directory on build"*, that also means malicious project files can delete just about anything from just about anywhere. Or worse. The compromise is the *"Hey. We've given you the keys to the kingdom, but we don't recognize this project. Are you sure you want to open this? We're not responsible if it does something stupid"* warning message that you mentioned.

Now consider that many developers run Visual Studio as an administrator.

Here are some of those attack vectors:

**Pre- and Post-Build Events**
In it's simplest form, untrusted projects could execute a Pre-Build event that would delete files. Or worse. Just about anything can be executed within a Build event. This is the 101 stuff that happens on Compile.

**Executions on Project Open**
Visual Studio project files are nothing more than big MSBuild configurations. There are a few MSBuild targets that Visual Studio executes when you open a project, all to support the tooling. These targets include Compile, ResolveAssemblyReferences, ResolveCOMReferences, GetFrameworkPaths, and CopyRunEnvironmentFiles. If any of these targets exist, the tasks within them are also executed. Delete files, or worse.

See: 'Design-Time Execution' at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx

**IntelliSense**
Part of that *tooling* mentioned above includes IntelliSense, which executes the `Compile` task within MSBuild; the CSC/VBC must be executed to get all of the IntelliSense functionality. Because of the nature of IntelliSense, this task is repeatedly executed as you work, rather than the opportunities above that are just run once on open.

See: 'Design-Time IntelliSense' at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx

**Hidden Elsewhere in MSBuild**
There is a sea of other routine MSBuild targets that you will manually execute throughout your day, including Build, Rebuild, Test, and Clean. Yes, keep in mind that even `clean` is a build target, so `Clean` could delete more than just your old `\bin` directories.

**NuGet**
Malicious projects may also expose systems via NuGet. Though Package Restore would not be an issue, the `packages.config` could specify a different Repository Source. Then, when you install a new package, such as `install-package jquery`, NuGet will retrieve the jQuery package from the untrusted alternate, rather than from nuget.org. This malicious jQuery package could have all sorts of other 'Goodies' within it that would be executed as a part of the package installation.

This is not a security vulnerability from NuGet, because "you" specified an alternate package source; this is by design, such as Corporations that have their own internal package repository.

## What you can do?

At the end of the day, what can you do about this? The answer really is to just not open projects from untrusted sources. The project's `packages.config` file could be analyzed before you open it, but the big exposure is through MSBuild. Unless you are quite adept at reading through MSBuild schema, I would steer clear.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I'm going to keep the question open for a while to see if anyone else has additional ideas, I think it's an interesting subject.