# Security risks of cloning visual c# projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security, github, malware

I know that opening a visual studio project from an untrustworthy source can present sucurity risks beyond the obvious danger of the target code itself being malicious([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611951/untrustworthy-projects-in-visual-studio)). Does cloning a git hub project present the same risks, or would it only copy the source code? Thanks in advance for any and all help!

More information: The project I'm concerned about is a visual c# project located [here](https://github.com/rudderdon/mailmerge2000).

Comment: What do you mean by "cloning"? The attack vector is the `.proj` file, because it is nothing more than an MSBuild script itself. So if you copy/clone that, then you've copied the attack vector also.

Comment: By "cloning" I mean going to Team>Manage Connections>Local Git Repositories>Clone then entering the git url. Whether this exposes one to security risks by downloading the MSBuild scripts is precisely my question.

Comment: Is the `.proj` file identical after you clone? If yes, then you have your answer. (Sorry, haven't used git yet.) You can think of this as a fancier form of SQL Injection:  At runtime, "code" gets interpreted by system. Whether that code is the original code or a copy is inconsequential; the interpreter will interpret both the same way.